# Append error in python

Tags: python, list, julia

I am using JuliaBox to run python code in python 2.

My code is as follows:

```
l=[]

l.append(5)
```

And the following is the error I got:

> type Array has no field append

But I have used `append` as given in the python documentation. https://docs.python.org/2.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual traceback and full code to produce this error? Those two lines surely would not produce that error.

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question. Are you 100% sure that you're running Python? If you're running Juliabox, wouldn't your code be [Julia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%28programming_language%29) code?

Comment: My code is of only two lines . @CoryKramer

Comment: It is python 2 @Kevin

Comment: Copy paste the complete Traceback

Comment: How do you know it's Python 2?

Comment: can you run `dir(l)`

Comment: In [21]:

l=[]

l.append(5)


type Array has no field append

while loading In[21], in expression starting on line 2

@sgp

Comment: @Kevin In julia box, it shows which version we are using.

Comment: print `type(l)` I don't think it is a python lsit object

Comment: I'd like to see a screenshot of the part where it tells you what version you're using. My current guess is, it's saying that Julia is _compatible_ with Python 2.6; as in, Julia can invoke Python 2.6 code if you specially instruct it to. But you're not specially instructing it to, so it doesn't know what to do with this weird non-Julia code.

Comment: I linked the screen shot.

Comment: Why people are ready to downvote the questions without proper  discussion ?

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot. I was able to replicate your error by signing in to JuliaBox, selecting "New" from the dropdown list on the right, choosing "Notebooks -> Python 2", and entering Python code in the subsequent window. It definitely only properly runs Julia code in there. I don't know why they added this option if it doesn't work properly. If you want to learn Python, I suggest downloading a standalone interpreter rather than depending on this website.

Comment: @hanugm I think the downvotes are because your question at first seemed unbelievable.  But you are right - I have replicated it also.

Comment: This is a known bug in JuliaBox: https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaBox/issues/233

Comment: Nice work @MattB. - I'm disappointed I didn't find that when I had a quick look through the issues.

Answer (score 11):

You are using Julia not Python:

[image]

Comment: If I am using julia then why is it showing python2. It shows julia version for julia .

Comment: This is using the console option in Juliabox.  The OP is creating a new notebook in the file area, allegedly working with a Python2 kernel, but it's actually running Julia.  The error is reproducible.

Comment: @JRichardSnape In OPs unedited post the use of a notebook in the file area wasn't made clear. Regardless, my intention with this answer was to show the error produced showed OP was actually using Julia, answering their question "Where I went wrong?".

Comment: Sure - understood - the OP question was somewhat unclear and it was totally unverifiable before the screenshot was posted.  I just thought I'd try to add some info

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are obviously doing anything wrong.  I can reproduce your problem by clicking `New` on the [JuliaBox.org](http://juliabox.org) landing page and selecting `Python 2` in the Notebooks subsection of the menu.  This creates a new notebook which you would expect to be running against the python kernel and gives you some visual indications that it *is* running python.

***However***

In fact, it is not running Python, it is running Julia.  You can test this by, for instance simply typing `sin(0.3)`.  This would fail in Python, but gives you a result in Julia.  Similarly `println("Hello world!")`

I'm not familiar with IJulia or Juliabox, so can't state categorically whether this is a bug, but it certainly feels like one and is unexpected and counter intuitive behaviour at best.

My final comment is to try a different interpreter - if you want something with a similar look and feel, you could always use iPython directly.  As a bonus, you'll be able to use Python 3 instead of being stuck with 2.6!

***EDIT***

As highlighted by [**Matt B.** in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779751/append-error-in-python/30781409#comment49625807_30779751), this is a [known bug in IJulia](http://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaBox/issues/233)

Answer (score 3):

Your Python code is perfectly valid. Try another interpreter.